# Invalid conversion using numbered indexes with the new API

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I am facing a problem with the new syntax.
When parsing the following yaml file:

```
S1:
    data_type: spr
    guid: 1 
S2:
    data_type: spr
    guid: 2
```

using the following code:

```
#include "yaml.h"
int main () {
    YAML::Node testNode = YAML::LoadFile("data/Sprites.yaml");

    std::cout<<"type "<<testNode["S1"]["data_type"].as<std::string>()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"type "<<testNode[1]["data_type"].as<std::string>()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The first line works and outputs "type spr", while the second line doesn't, throwing a YAML::TypedBadConversion < std::string >.

Shouldn't them both have the same output? Or does numbered indexes work only on sequences and not on maps? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In YAML, maps are not ordered, so it doesn't make sense to ask for the "first entry" of a map. Instead, `testNode[1]` refers to the entry of the map with key `1`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: That explains things. I guess I'll list all the names in a sequence at the top of the yaml file.